# Number of permutations, basic question

Tags: combinatorics

What are the number of permutations in the following simple case:

John has a wardrobe with:

- $3$ trousers
- $2$ shirts
- $2$ pairs of socks
- $4$ vests
- $4$ pairs of gloves
- $5$ jackets

Every morning John has to choose one item from each group (so he cannot leave home, for instance, without gloves). What is the number of possible combinations of clothes?

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you have any idea what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look a starter in Permutations. So let me explain in detail.

What is the number of ways in which John can select a trouser ? Answer is : $3$ ways. Because he can choose any one from three.

What is the number of ways in which John can select a shirt? Answer is : $2$ ways. Because he can choose any one from two.

Similarly for the other items.

So total number of ways he can select $1$ each from trousers, shirts, socks, vests, gloves, jackets will be :

$$ 3*2*2*4*4*5 = 960$$

Since you are a starter better get to know about Permutation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) before attempting such questions.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer, looks really simple. I already thought about multiplying, but I had expected in that way that many combinations are repeated.

Comment: Just think for yourself if any combination is getting repeated. If so try to find them out(which you will not because they will never repeat)

Comment: Since you are confused, why don't you start with this, say he has only $2$ shirts and $2$ trousers. So what are all the possibilities ?Let the shirts be $S_1,S_2$ and the trousers be $T_1, T_2$. What are the possibilities ? Try to find out on your own and you will understand it better.